# how to display error message in save method of django

Tags: python, django

I want to display error message in case the instance I am creating is more than the maximum limit I have specified in a certain model. This is a inner condition.

I know that we can hide the `+` and override the `has_add_permission` method. This is used for user authentication in my application.

However, I wish to allow the instance to be created for a certain login who is a superuser based on the inner condition.

`ValidationError` gives me error `u' max...' ValidationError at the url...`

Can anyone guide?

Comment: Short answer: you can't. It's too late for validation from the save() method.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what an "inner condition" is.

However, you don't do this in the `save` method. You do it in a [validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/validators/). For instance, you could define a `clean` method on your model to handle this, or use a custom form with the validation in.